# How to put breakpoints in an application linked to a static library with Clion?

Tags: c++, debugging, static-libraries, static-linking, clion

I'd like to debug an application linked to a static library with Clion 2016.1.1, but whenever I run the target in debug mode, the execution won't break in my defined breakpoints.

However it'll break if there is a SIGSEGV

Here's my CmakeLists.txt

```cmake
# Header files
set(HEADER_FILES include/game/Game.h)

# Source files
set(SOURCE_FILES src/game/Game.cpp)

# gameengine library
add_library(gameengine STATIC ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

# gamesample executable
add_executable(gamesample src/main.cpp) # I'd like to debug step 
target_link_libraries(gamesample gameengine)

# tests
include_directories(lib/googletest)
enable_testing()
add_executable(tests test/tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests gameengine)
target_link_libraries(tests gtest gtest_main)
add_test(NAME test COMMAND tests)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the bundled gdb with CLion,

I switched to /usr/bin/gdb and the debugging started to work.